# What technical terms apply to non-linear transforms that retain rank order?

Tags: data-transformation, terminology

I am almost certain there is/are a technical term(s) to describe transformations (e.g $x^2$ or $log(x)$ for positive numbers) which are non-linear transformations of the variable $x$, but retain the rank order of x.  But I am drawing a blank and my google searches have be ineffective.  What technical terms apply to these sorts of transformations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The phrase you're looking for is [monotone functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function), also referred to as monotonic functions.